# How get the version of an EAR module at runtime in Java EE 6 (JBoss AS 7)?

Tags: jboss, maven-3, jboss7.x, java-ee-6, versioning

I have a EAR module with some sub modules (using Maven). I would like to display in the Web application (one of the sub modules) the version of the EAR.

How do I get the version of EAR in runtime?

I'm using JavaEE 6 and JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final

Answer (score 0):

I get the name of my app by calling this code from my EJB bean:

```
String appName = (String) (new InitialContext()).lookup( "java:app/AppName" );
```

Comment: and how I get the version?

Answer (score 0):

In our project we get a hold of the ear /META-INF/MANIFEST.MF (java.util.jar.Manifest)

Then we can do

```
manifest.getMainAttributes().getValue(Attributes.Name.IMPLEMENTATION_VERSION);
```